# Is there any reason to upgrade to windows 8.1 if I avoid using metro?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, modern-ui

I run windows 8 on a multimonitor setup.
I use classic shell, and avoid using metro if at all possible.
I do not use the "hot corners" and am not interested in desktop backgrounds except for solid grey.
Also I am not interested in using the windows store or whatever it is called.

Is there any reason left for me to upgrade to windows 8.1?
Or is it just a risk that my settings and system will get hosed with no benefit to me?
Will anything work better for me after an upgrade?

Comment: This question really isn't a good fit for SU, it's mostly opinion based outside of a benchie or two.  If you are happy where you are, I wouldn't change it.  But that's just me.  W8.1 didn't really "fix" any of the common complaints anyway and added minimal extra - afaik.

Comment: So "no" would be the answer then?

Comment: That's subjective.  For me, I wouldn't if I was happy with my current configuration, but I can't say there is absolutely no reason to not - but you can check the supposed "upgrades" verses your needs and decide for yourself..

Comment: @nerdwaller Whether you need to upgrade because of features is pretty subjective. No argument on that. But there is the future security-status of the OS to consider. In lieu of Microsofts track-record in the past I consider that fact, not opinion. See my answer.

Comment: @dontomaso - How about that Windows 8 in a very short amount of time ( about 18 months ) won't be supported by Microsoft.  Microsoft going forward is only going to support Windows 8.1.  This means going forward future versions of Visual Studio, IE, Office are unlikely to even install on Windows 8.0

Comment: There is really no reason not to...

Comment: @dontomaso I keep hearing this but according to M$ EOL doesn't occur for Windows 8 till 2018, it makes no mention of whether this includes Windows 8.1 or strictly Windows 8... http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/products/lifecycle

Comment: I would like to answer this question if it is reopened. I do not use Metro, but Win8.1 has 3 features I use which do not exist in Win7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, for most use-cases, 8.1 is just a re-branded service-pack 1 for 8.0.
Besides for the improvements in Metro and the screen handling (both of little use to you) and to power-management (only really interesting if you have a laptop).
It might be that in the near future Microsoft will force 8.1 down your throat anyway by making it a mandatory "security" upgrade. (They can retire 8.0 very quickly by limiting future security hotfixes to 8.1 only.)
If the MS service-record regarding post-service-pack security hotfixes is any guide they will at some point hardly do any testing anymore of new hotfixes against the pre-service-pack version of the OS. If a hotfix breaks on the OS without service-pack they will simple state that the service-pack is a requirement for the hotfix. (And thereby forcing the upgrade on everybody who needs the hotfix.)
This has happened frequently on NT4, Windows 2000, XP, Vista and Windows 7. I don't think MS will change their tune with Windows 8.

It's a free upgrade though, so why not do it **after making a good backup**, so you can undo if it screws up.

I wouldn't trust the build-in backup of Windows. I have heard a substantial number of horror-stories about it (and I have had issues myself as well).
In a case like this it is always best to make a full image-based backup to an external HD or network-share, from a CD or USB boot medium. (Don't make a backup from WITHIN Windows itself.)
Several commercial backup programs offer a free trail edition that you could use for such a one-time situation.
(Make sure the trail version will actually let you restore. Some trail versions will backup, but not do restore without buying a license.)

And there is always the free CloneZilla, which is included in the PartedMagic live-CD (or USB stick).

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you should update to 8.1 is that the [support for the original Windows 8 ends in 2015](http://www.neowin.net/news/windows-8-users-have-two-years-to-update-to-windows-81-before-support-ends) and you are forced to upgrade to get new updates.

Answer (score 1):

8.1 replaces quite a bit more than the UI, and is significantly more stable at running many apps. Replace it after a complete backup.

Answer (score 1):

If you mostly use the desktop app and style applications, then Windows 8.1 would be useful to you since it has the option of showing the Desktop right after login (instead of the Start screen). It also has an option to return you to the Desktop after closing a metro app (instead of sending you to the Start screen).